# Aurelia Dialog: Show Wait Spinner During Async Activate

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I'm using aurelia-dialog to display details of an account.

All the examples I've seen of aurelia-dialog involve passing an entire object to the dialog and using that object as the viewmodel for the dialog. What I want to do is pass the ID and run an AJAX call to get the detail data.

It's simple enough to get that working, but then when I return a promise from the `activate` call on the dialog's viewmodel, the dialog doesn't display at all until the promise is resolved. That's a bummer, because there's a delay.

I'd like the dialog to display right away and to show a spinner until the promise resolves. Is there a simple way to do this? Has anyone seen or done this?

Comment: `the dialog doesn't display at all until the promise is resolved` that's the intended design you can *not* return anything and it will show.  In this case you would just flag something when the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

`the dialog doesn't display at all until the promise is resolved` that's the intended design you can not return anything and it will show. In this case you would just flag something when the promise is resolved.

```
export class MyDialogVM {
  showSpinner = false;
  // ...
  activate(id) {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.http.get(`/my-api/${id}`).then(result => {
      this.showSpinner = false;
    });
  }
}
```

And your dialog view

```
<template>
  <!-- other stuff -->
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" show.bind="showSpinner"></i>
  <!-- other stuff -->
</template>
```